# Is it possible to combine Regex with several characters being replaced?

Tags: jquery, regex

So I'm currently learning jQuery and I learned about regex recently and decided to put it into play.  What I've done works perfectly fine, but I have a feeling I'm going the long way about things.

I've looked online and I'm certain you can combine regex, but it looks really confusing and I really don't understand it!

**Here's what I have:**

```
var trackingPlus = contentURL.text().replace(/ /g, '+')
                                    .replace(/&/g, 'And')
                                    .replace(/%/g, 'PC')
                                    .replace(/!/g, '')
                                    .replace(/£/g, '')
                                    .replace(/,/g, '')
                                    .replace(/\./g, '')
                                    .replace(/\+>/g, '');
```

Is there any way to combine this into one "thing"?

Or if not, maybe the last 5 as they're all being replaced with nothing?

Any help, or explanation would be really appreciated!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) here. Simply put, a character class is a way of denoting a set of characters in such a way that **one character** of the set is matched.

A character class matches only a single character, so `[!£,.+]` would match one character from the list `!`, `£`, `,`, `.`,`+`. It's important to note that the usual regex meta-characters (`*`, `+` etc.) are normal characters inside a character class and do not require additional escaping.

```
var trackingPlus = contentURL.text().replace(/ /g, '+')
                                    .replace(/&/g, 'And')
                                    .replace(/%/g, 'PC')
                                    .replace('/[!£,.+]/g', '');
```

Comment: You would'nt even need to use regular expressions for the first three replacements. :)

Comment: @YMMD. But... but... it looks so nice when stacked together! :D

Comment: That's what I thought too haha!  Thanks for your help! :)